# Parking attendant using semaphores

Tags: operating-system, ipc, semaphore

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> The parking attendant (or valet) manages a parking lot of **M** spots.
>   He'll personally pick some cars up from a '*temporary parking lot*' of **N**
>   spots, where the owners of their cars leave them with the key on. You
>   will need to implement a *thread* **carOwner()** and a *thread* **carAttendant()**
>   which will respectively represent the owner of the car, and the
>   parking attendant (or valet). *These threads need to be synchronized
>   using semaphores*. Each owner needs to verify the availability of a
>   *temporary spot* to park his car, waiting for the parking attendant to
>   park it in the *parking lot*; in case of no temporary spot available,
>   the owner *will leave* the parking lot. You'll need to use - then - a
>   counter variable **nFree**, to count all the *temporary spots*, and will
>   make sure of properly protecting it. The parking attendant, waiting
>   for car owners, will wait for new cars at the '*temporary parking lot*'
>   and will update **nFree** as well. Please use, for the synchronization,
>   *semaphores* **newCar** and **inCharge**, properly initialized.

I think a good way to face it is by using the *Sleeping Barber problem*'s algorithms, since it's quite similar. So here are the threads I created.

```
thread carAttendant() {             
     while TRUE {
        wait(newCar);
        wait(mutex);
        nFree = nFree + 1;
        signal(inCharge);
        signal(mutex);
        parkTheCar();
     }
}

thread carDriver() {
    wait(mutex);
    if (nFree > 0) {
       nFree = nFree - 1;
       signal(newCar);
       signal(mutex);
       wait(inCharge);
       leaveCarWithKeys();
    } else {
       signal(mutex);
       leaveParkingLot();
    }
}
```

Am I close to the solution? Here, I think I still miss something: for example, does the parking attendant behave the same way of the barber (will the car owner need to wake up the parking attendant)? Also, there's another difference: the barber needs to handle only one chair, while the parking attendant needs to handle M parking spots (instead of only one resource, we have M). How should I implement it?

Comment: It looks proper to me. For M slots: You can have a counter `mFree`. Assuming only `carAttendant` uses it, you don't need any mutex protection for that. But question is not clear in terms of handling M slots. Clearly carAttendant() has to check if a slot is available (`mFree > 0`) before picking the car. But when to remove a car from M slot is not clear.